# Get the location of the caller of a module method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I have a helper module that I use in my views, I'd like to be able to get the source file location of the file that I call the helper method on. Ideally I'd like it to work like this:

/views/posts/index.hmtl.erb

```
<%= my_method ' method_param' %>
```

my_helper.rb

```
module MyHelper
  def my_method(method_param)
    location = self.some_way_of_finding_caller_loaction+method_param
  end
end
```

Which would then render to:

"/views/posts/index.hmtl.erb method_param"

in my view.

Is there anyway for me to do this?

Comment: [`caller[0]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller)?

Comment: @mudasobwa please post it as an answer or mark it as a duplicate.